# How to define image corner colors using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Suppose i have following image , how to find its corner colors ?
I found something like

[image]

```
image = Image.open('my_image.png')
image = image.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
```

but now stuck. In this case it's should be (0,0,0) (in RGB) for every corner

Comment: Naive approach: Get width and height of the image, and check the four corner pixels one by one!?

Comment: Yea, it's should work, thank you!